# Exporting CSV with Diacritics causes strange characters to appear in output

Tags: linux, windows, scala, csv

I export a csv in Scala/Spray and it works nice on my **Windows** machine but fails on **Linux** machine.

The response from both OS are identical:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, Auth-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Auth-Token
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=Enter report title.csv
Content-Length:229
Content-Type:text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Fri, 07 Feb 2014 22:17:40 GMT
Server:spray-can/1.2.0
```

I am wondering why the OS can make a difference?

When exporting from linux after jar is deployed, diacritics are replaced with strange chars.

For instance this `Café macchiato`
 is fine when exporting from Windows but it appears like `CafÃ© macchiato`
 when exporting from Linux.

Comment: How do you view your files in both OSes?

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov I export from my local env and view in Win 7 - Excel and the same when I export from the website hosted on Linux env.

Answer (score 0):

Please never ever use Excel for text-oriented files. It screws up stuff. Use an editor like vim or Notepad++ where you can inspect the bytes and actually see whether your stuff is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

To help Excel recognize character encoding you can add a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the beginning of the file. For example:

```
def prepareBomOutputStream(outputFile: String) = {
  val os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)
  os.write(239)
  os.write(187)
  os.write(191)
  os
}
```

You can also check if in both cases you get exact same encoding and not a subset of the encoding. For instance on Windows you might get `ISO-8859-15` instead. You can most likely set encoding explicitly in your CSV export code/library. To check encoding on Linux you can use:

```
$ file -ib /tmp/test.csv 
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

or even something like `hexdump`.